# SublimeText3ファイル保存に関して

Tags: javascript, typescript, sublimetext

SublimeText3にて新規でファイルを作成し、保存時にtsx形式で保存してもファイル名の最後に.jsがついしまいます。
どなたか解決方法ご存知でしょうか。

Comment: 私の環境では、.jsがつかず、普通に.tsx形式で保存することができました。
何か設定をいじっていたり、関係しそうなプラグインをインストールしたりしていませんか？